# Scale to fit a Flex 4 - Flash application

Tags: flash, flex4, scale

SO I have a flash application that Dynamically changes height and width of it self and components depending on the stage height and width.

this application is going to run alone on a screen the height and width of the screen can be anything ( testing and the application works perfectly and adjusts its components and all required objects in it on the screen )

while giving this application its flashvars and text information from a window .. which is connected to a preview window that has a fixed width and height were the application is viewed but it adjusts it self to the width and height of that fixed window.

I do have the width and height that application is actually going to be viewed on the screen with.

how can I scale the application (Scale to fit in the preview window)  its OK if it has blank at the top and bottom or left and right depending on the real width and height.

Comment: the embed tag used to place the SWF in the HTML page can control how the application scales. i assume you want to have the app take up the entire screen and fluidly resized itself?

Comment: A better way to do this according to me would be to give your inner components a percentage width and height rather than in pixels.

Comment: That way you would not need to change the height/width of each inner component each time there is a resize. Programmatically you can change the percentage width and height using the percentageWidth and percentageHeight properties

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use stage.stageWidth/stage.stageHeight to get the embed's size. And use the Event.RESIZE event to handle when the stage size changes at runtime. Then you just need some rather simple scaling logic to keep your aspect ratio is check.

something like:

```
// disables streching
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

// listen to stage being resizes
addEventListener(Event.RESIZED, handleResized);

// adjust UI to original size
setSize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

// handle the resized event, and update your UI's dimension
function handleResized(evt:Event):void
{
    setSize(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}

// updates your UI
function setSize(wid:int, hgt:int):void
{
    container.width = wid;
    container.height = hgt;
}
```

will scale your app to the stage size. if you need to maintain an aspect ratio of your application, then you can either adjust the way you are embedding the SWF or you can handle the aspect ratio logic yourself in the setSize function.